# How to change the value of a kendo bound html input

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendoui grid with a custom popup for editing.

In this popup I have an input which is bound to a value of the grid:

```
<input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox" id="test" data-bind="value:SearchFilter">
```

This works fine. Click edit in the grid, change the value in the textbox and the value propagates to the grid.

But now I want to change the value of the textbox in javascript.. So I now have this:

```
$('#test').val("testvalue");
```

This indeed changes the value of the textbox, but upon save the new value isn't propagated to the grid. I guess because no change event occurs on the textbox.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need simulate change event. Try this code:

```
$('#test').val("testvalue").change();
```

Comment: Thanks.. It works.. I tried many tricks but this is awesome... :)

Comment: but it also triggers the validation required tooltip. when there is value in input its should not open required msg tooltip.. Please help...?

Answer (score 7):

I tried the above answer but did not work for me. Although the value had indeed changed, the view did not reflect that fact. This worked for me:

```
       var myvar = $("#myid").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
       myvar.value("newValue");
       myvar.trigger("change", { value: myvar.value() });
```