# Testing Kendo UI Grid with Selenium / Geb

Tags: jquery, grails, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, geb

I'm trying to write a functional test for a Kendo UI Grid in my application. In my test, I  click on a button to add a new row to the grid, I then want to move through each of the cells, assigning a value to the input field contained in the cell as I go. I can do this 'by hand' in a browser, and it works with no issues. However, if I try to automate this process using Geb, the value entered into each cell is cleared out as soon as I tab away from the input field.

One observation is that when I perform this test by hand, once I enter a value in the input I see a black triangle (i.e. the kendo 'dirty' icon) appear in the top left hand corner of the input. If I try to do this programmatically in my test, I do not see this icon.

I have tried various different methods for populating the input field, such as:

```
1. productDescriptionField.find("input",0).value("some description")
2. productDescriptionField.find("input",0) << "some description"
3. (driver as JavascriptExecutor).executeScript("jQuery('.k-input').val('some description')")
```

where `productDescriptionField` is a geb selector for the input field shown in the HTML snippet below:

```
<td data-role="editable" class="k-edit-cell" id="grid_active_cell" role="gridcell">
    <input data-bind="value:description" name="description" class="k-input k-textbox" type="text">
</td>
```

How can I better simulate what I, as a human being using a web browser, do when interacting with the kendo grid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem seems to be, that the grid is not aware of the programmatically change of the input field. this happens because the [change-event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#events-change) of the grid is not fired if this is done programatically. Due to this, you just have to trigger the change event by yourself ([change-kendo-html-input-field-programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954977/how-to-change-the-value-of-a-kendo-bound-html-input)).

In your case your third option should be changed to the following:

```
var changeValue = "$('.k-input').val('some description')";
var triggerChange = "$('.k-input').change();"
(driver as JavascriptExecutor).executeScript(changeValue + "; " + triggerChange)
```

Comment: Looks promising - I'll give this a try tomorrow.